# Setting variables in a KSH spawned process

Tags: multithreading, variables, ksh

I have a lengthy menu script that relies on a few command outputs for it's variables. These commands take several seconds to run each and I would like to spawn new processes to set these variables.  It would look something like this:

```
VAR1=`somecommand` &
VAR2=`somecommand` &
...
wait
echo $VAR1 $VAR2
```

The problem is that the processes are spawned and die with those variables they set.  I realize that I can do this by sending these to a file and then reading that but I would like to do it without a temp file.  Any ideas?

Comment: Korn shell does not yet support multithreading.  It might be supported one day, but not right now.  Or are you confusing threads and processes?

Comment: I think I understand your issue, the problem is that you need either multithreading or non-blocking pipes or sockets.  Right now Korn shell supports neither.  You need a more powerful language.

Comment: Yes my mistake.  The & will spawn off a new process which is not a thread.  And I am confined to ksh for this so I cannot use a more powerful language.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the whole process' output using command substitution, like:

```
VAR1=$(somecommand &)
VAR2=$(somecommand &)
...
wait
echo $VAR1 $VAR2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method still blocks until the process completes because it waits on the "somecommand" to complete before setting the variable.

Comment: As you don't want to be blocked, there's no way to achieve that with a different process. Because, `&` creates a new process and processes can't direct exchange data with some IPC mechanism.
Why you don't want to use temporary files? You can delete the right after you get your data if you don't want them.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather clunky, but works for me.  I have three scripts.

cmd.sh is your "somecommand", it is a test script only:

```
#!/bin/ksh
sleep 10
echo "End of job $1"
```

Below is `wrapper.sh`, which runs a single command, captures the output, signals the parent when done, then writes the result to stdout:

```
#!/bin/ksh
sig=$1
shift
var=$($@)
kill -$sig $PPID
echo $var
```

and here is the parent script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

trap "read -u3 out1" SIGUSR1
trap "read -p out2" SIGUSR2

./wrapper.sh SIGUSR1 ./cmd.sh one |&
exec 3<&p
exec 4>&p

./wrapper.sh SIGUSR2 ./cmd.sh two |&
wait
wait
echo "out1: $out1, out2: $out2"
echo "Ended"
```

2x wait because the first will be interrupted.

In the parent script I am running the wrapper twice, once for each job, passing in the command to be run and any arguments.  The `|&` means "pipe to background" - run as a co-process.

The two `exec` commands copy the pipe file descriptors to fds 3 and 4.  When the jobs are finished, the wrapper signals the main process to read the pipes.  The signals are caught using the `trap`, which read the pipe for the appropriate child process, and gather the resulting data.

Rather convoluted and clunky, but it appears to work.

Comment: Here is a link explaining how co-processes work:http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/classes/ksh/coprocesses.html#top