# Read all lines at the same time individually - Solaris ksh

Tags: while-loop, solaris, ksh

I need some help with a script. Solaris 10 and ksh.

I Have a file called /temp.list with this content:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
```

So, I have a script which reads this list and executes some commands using the lines values:

```
FILE_TMP="/temp.list"
while IFS= read line
do
ping $line
done < "$FILE_TMP"
```

It works, but it executes the command on line 1. When it's over, it goes to the line 2, and it goes successively until the end. I would like to find a way to execute the command ping at the same time in each line of the list. Is there a way to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Marcus Quintella

Comment: You could store the lines in a variable and ping them afterwards? Although realistically pinging things simultaneously won't be possible since you can't send two packets simultaneously.

Comment: The ping is just an example.. I need to run other commands, but if it works with ping, it will work with the other comands too!

Comment: Running commands simultaneously is called multi-threading. Googling "ksh multithreading" gives some good suggestions (i.e. [1](http://alexhanin.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/multithreading-with-nothing-but-korn.html), [2](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch08_05.htm), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298541/setting-variables-in-a-ksh-spawned-process)).

Answer (score 0):

As Ari's suggested, googling ksh multithreading will produce a lot of ideas/solutions.

A simple example:

```
FILE_TMP="/temp.list"
while IFS= read line
do
ping $line &
done < "$FILE_TMP"
```

The trailing '&' says to kick the ping command off in the background, allowing loop processing to continue while the ping command is running in the background.

'course, this is just the tip of the proverbial iceberg as you now need to consider:

- multiple ping commands are going to be dumping output to stdout (ie, you're going to get a mish-mash of ping output in your console), so you'll need to give some thought as to what to do with multiple streams of output (eg, redirect to a common file? redirect to separate files?)
- you need to have some idea as to how you want to go about managing and (possibly) terminating commands running in the background [ see **jobs**, **ps**, **fg**, **bg**, **kill** ]
- if running in a shell script you'll likely find yourself wanting to suspend the main shell script processing until all background jobs have completed [ see **wait** ]